# How to test if a wire is connected with an Arduino

Tags: voltage, current, wire

I have an Arduino to control an actuator which moves up and down reversing the current using a couple relays controlled with the Arduino.

I would like to be able to detect when the actuator is up and when the actuator is down. When the actuator is up one of the wires in the relay becomes disconnected and when is fully down it is the other wire that becomes disconnected (that is, not connected to either VCC or ground.)

Is there a way to test is the a wire is connected? I thought I could measure the voltage but I get 0 volts, which is the same voltage I get when connected to ground.

Comment: please post a schematic diagram of your circuit

Answer (score 1):

You have linear actuator that disconnets itself when reaching its limit position. To determine whether it reached one of the limit positions you can check whether the device is draining any current. You can place shunt resistor of small value and measure the voltage on it by arduino's analog input pin.

Comment: yes, I thought about this possibility. however it is not perfect. For instance, in the case the actuator breaks, for any reason, in the middle. It may not drive current, but it is still not in the top or down position....

Answer (score 1):

if a wire is connected to nothing, then it can have any voltage compared to ground.
However, the measurement circuit itself tends to pull (very weakly) the signal toward 0V if there is nothing else to pull it elsewhere.

One solution that would probably work would be to add a weak voltage dividor to each wire, pulling it toward some "middle" value (for example Vcc/2)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flq27O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If your wire is "strongly" connected to GND, VCC (or any other voltage), then the resistors will not have any significant effect (excepted waisting a fraction of a mA (ie Vcc/10k if your wire is GND or VCC). If the wire is no longer connected, then the voltage will be around Vcc/2